# jquery how to activate function when reached to specific line in code

Tags: php, jquery

I want to activate this jquery function when I reached to specific code in the page?
(code in php).

```
  $(document).ready (function(){
                $("#alert").click(function showAlert() {
                    $("#success-alert").css('display','block');
                    $("#success-alert").alert();
                    $("#success-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
                        $("#success-alert").alert('close');
                    });
                });
            });
```

I tried to use .load() and .ready() function but without any success.For now I work with .click().

Comment: Eh? Php loads on the server and jQuery for the client, meaning that the php will finish it's code regardless of where you paste in the jQuery, the only solution I can think of is with AJAX

Comment: Yes not sure what you mean by the 'code in php' part, do you mean you want to call the showAlert function when you scroll down the page and reach a certain element?

Comment: i clarify my question, i want this code:
  $('#success-alert').css('display','block');
$('#success-alert').alert();
$('#success-alert').fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
$('#success-alert').alert('close');
<div style='display:none' class='alert alert-success' id='success-alert'>
        </div> work only after specified php code.

Answer (score 0):

using PHP you say? Just make sure jQuery is included before this.

```
<?php
   echo '<script>' . 
            '$(document).ready (function(){' . 
                '$("#alert").click(function showAlert() {' . 
                    '$("#success-alert").css('display','block');' . 
                    '$("#success-alert").alert();' . 
                    '$("#success-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){' . 
                        '$("#success-alert").alert('close');' . 
                    '});' . 
               ' });' . 
            '}); ' . 
        '</script>';
?>
```

---

Also, because this is in a document.ready function - it doesn't matter where you place it. It will run when the document is ready. It also seems to be a listener for a click event, so it will only happen when you make that click too - your placing/timing of this code is totally irrelevant.

---

OK here is the deal. PHP is executed on the server side. This means that you cannot communicate with PHP and JavaScript simultaneously. I remember it took me a while to grasp this concept. For instance, you cannot use JavaScript variables in PHP, e.g. like so:

```
<script> var x = 2; </script>
<?php echo x; // or $x, or whatever ?>
```

But you can do the following:

```
<?php $x = 2 ?>
<script> var x = <?php echo $x; ?>; </script>
```

This will be evaluated in your browser as:

```
 <script> var x = 2; </script>
```